# How extract only numbers between double quotes, simple quotes or without them using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a Java code that processes events in real time, from which it extracts information using regex, recently it fails, after hours of debugging, I find that this value can arrive in the 3 ways that I leave here:

```
{"eventId":"25","started":"2022-07-29T18:37:38.717Z","finished":"2022-07-29T18:37:38.717Z","duration":0,"sessionId":"xxxx","personId":"1111111","status":"ok"}
{"eventId":'25',"started":"2022-07-29T18:37:38.717Z","finished":"2022-07-29T18:37:38.717Z","duration":0,"sessionId":"xxxx","personId":"1111111","status":"ok"}
{"eventId":25,"started":"2022-07-29T18:37:38.717Z","finished":"2022-07-29T18:37:38.717Z","duration":0,"sessionId":"xxxx","personId":"1111111","status":"ok"}
```

I have tried without success to modify the current regex that extracts the information, to extracts the `eventId` number `25` in any of the three cases:

```
(?<="eventId":)"(\w+)"(?=,)
```

Is there any way to achieve this? ... thanks in advance!

PS: That is a Dataflow java code and just need extract the number without double or single quotes.

Comment: This looks like JSON data, why not use a JSON parser readily available in Java?

Comment: Because that is a Dataflow java code and just need extract the number without double or single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If JSON parser is not available then here is a regex solution.

Java allows limited dynamism in lookbehind. You may use this regex:

```bash
(?<=\"eventId\":[\"']?)\w+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fnN0dR/1)

Note addition of an optional `"` or `'` inside the lookbehind condition.

**Code:**

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\"eventId\":[\"']?)\\w+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
while (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println("Match: " + matcher.group(0));
}
```